# Rendering a component multiple times with different props in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one component that I'm trying to render four times, each time with different props. To be a little more succinct with my code and not actually write out the JSX for the component and its props each time, I was trying to use `map` to create different instances of the component. Right now, here's what that looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Panel from './components/Panel';
import Results from './components/Results';
import Intro from './components/Intro';

const questionsMap = [0, 1, 2, 3];

class React extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super (props);
        this.state = {
            questions: ['question1', 'question2', 'question3', 'question4'],
            answers: ['answers1', 'answers2', 'answers3', 'answers4']
        }
        this.onSelect = this.onSelect.bind(this);
    }

    onSelect(value) {
        /* Some code for when buttons are clicked */
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <Intro />
            {questionsMap.map(i => {
            return <Panel question={this.state.questions.i} answers={this.state.answers.i} onSelect={this.onSelect} />
            })}
            <Results />
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Right now I'm getting an `Unexpected token` error pointing to the line under my render that starts with `{questionsMap.map()}`, aka the part where I'm trying to actually do the mapping I mentioned. I assume I'm using the wrong syntax to accomplish what I want?

Comment: for one thing you don't want to name your class React.  use something like class PanelContainer extends React.Component

Comment: Return just one element. Wrap it in a div or something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Panel from './components/Panel';
import Results from './components/Results';
import Intro from './components/Intro';

const questionsMap = [0, 1, 2, 3];

class React extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super (props);
        this.state = {
            questions: ['question1', 'question2', 'question3', 'question4'],
            answers: ['answers1', 'answers2', 'answers3', 'answers4']
        }
        this.onSelect = this.onSelect.bind(this);
    }

    onSelect(value) {
        /* Some code for when buttons are clicked */
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
              <Intro />
              {questionsMap.map(i => {
              return <Panel question={this.state.questions[i]} answers={this.state.answers[i]} onSelect={this.onSelect} />
            })}
              <Results />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

But there are a few things that are not exactly a good practice, I assume this is some sort of test so I don't expect that you will name one of your components `React`.

On top of that you could simply map through the state, I would change the code a bit like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; import Panel from './components/Panel'; import Results from './components/Results'; import Intro from './components/Intro';


class React extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super (props);
        this.state = {
            questions: ['question1', 'question2', 'question3', 'question4'],
            answers: ['answers1', 'answers2', 'answers3', 'answers4']
        }
        this.onSelect = this.onSelect.bind(this);
    }

    onSelect(value) {
        /* Some code for when buttons are clicked */
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
              <Intro />
              {this.state.questions.map((question, questionIndex) => {
                return (<Panel
                question={question}
                answers={this.state.answers[questionIndex]}
                onSelect={this.onSelect} />
              )
            })}
              <Results />
            </div>
        );
    } }

export default App;
```

Alternatively you could have an array of objects with a field named question and another named answer, just to give you another idea.

Comment: Ahh this is a fantastic answer, thank you! For the record, I do not name my components 'React'. I quickly through together an example instead of using my rather verbose actual code, and that was a typo. But regardless, thank you!

Comment: I figured no worries!

Comment: Mark one of answers as correct so people don't keep answering ;), let me know if you have any other question or things you need me to clarify!

Comment: I'm trying to mark yours as correct, but SO is telling me my question hasn't been posted for long enough.

Comment: How can we access the props received in component <Panel /> on the basis of their index?

Answer (score 0):

At first, render can return only one element. You should wrap your components with `div`. At second, `this.state.questions.i` is wrong syntax. Use `this.state.questions[i]`.
Finally, I think there's the better approach:

```
return (
  <div>
    <Intro />
    {
      this.state.questions.map((question, i) => {
        return <Panel question={question} answers={this.state.answers[i]} onSelect={this.onSelect} />
      })
    }
    <Results />
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Dont name your class `React`
2. Unless you're using React 16 you need to wrap everything inside a div (on render method)
3. You don't need `questionsMap` . You can just use the index that `map` gives you for free, the `map` function's first argument is the element, and the second will be the index.
4. Deconstruct your questions and answer inside render, before the return, like so: `const { 
   questions, answers } = this.state; For readability.
5. Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

`return` method expects only 1 child and in your example, it had 3 children ie:

- Intro component
- an array of `<Panel>`s
- Result component.

to fix this, simplest way is to inclose within `<div>...</div>` tags

or in the case where this extra div hinders with the styling, you can simply enclose within `<>...</>` tags

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are returning more than one element which is invalid in react if you want to return more than one element you can either wrap them inside a div which makes an extra element on the DOM or you can use React fragment

case 1:

```
    render () {
        return (
            <>        //<React.fragment //either you the empty tag or the one with React.fragment they are both are valid
                <Intro />
                {questionsMap.map((_,i) => {
                    return <Panel question={this.state.questions[i]} answers= 
                {this.state.answers[i]} onSelect={this.onSelect} />})}
                <Results />
            </>       //</React.fragment> 
        );
    }
```

case 2:

```
    render () {
        return (
            <div>       
                <Intro />
                {questionsMap.map((_,i) => {
                    return <Panel question={this.state.questions[i]} answers= 
                {this.state.answers[i]} onSelect={this.onSelect} />})}
                <Results />
            </div> 
        );
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You haven't used the map function correctly.

Please check with the below code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Panel from './components/Panel';
import Results from './components/Results';
import Intro from './components/Intro';

const questionsMap = [0, 1, 2, 3];

class React extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super (props);
        this.state = {
            questions: ['question1', 'question2', 'question3', 'question4'],
            answers: ['answers1', 'answers2', 'answers3', 'answers4']
        }
        this.onSelect = this.onSelect.bind(this);
    }

    onSelect(value) {
        /* Some code for when buttons are clicked */
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <Intro />
            {questionsMap.map((_,i) => {
            return <Panel question={this.state.questions[i]} answers={this.state.answers[i]} onSelect={this.onSelect} />
            })}
            <Results />
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

1st argument in map is the value and second argument is index. Since, we don't need value from map so I have given it as _.